# Verifiy corrupted PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, corrupt

I would like to detect corrupted PDF using PHP. I have been able to determine that on not corrupted pdf I have the tag "%%EOF" at the end of the file. I also checked for this tag on corrupted and it not appear.

I had the idea to automatically checked the validty of my PDF file before uploading it to my server.

```html
<?php
$file = file('good.pdf');

$endfile= $file[count($file) - 1];

echo gettype($endfile),"\n";
echo $endfile,"\n";

?>
```

I get this result

```html
string %%EOF
```

For now, everything seems to be fine, but I have an issue when comparing the results.

I tested this code

```html
<?php
$file = file('good.pdf');
$endfile= $file[count($file) - 1];
$n="%%EOF";

echo $endfile;
echo $n;

if ($endfile === $n) {
    echo "good";

} else {
    echo "corrupted";
}

?>
```

I get this result

```html
%%EOF %%EOF corrupted
```

I know that $endfile and $n are string but when i want to compare it, I never get the equality/match. I also tried with == but the result is the same.

I also tried it like that :

```html
<?php
$file = file('good.pdf');
$endfile= $file[count($file) - 1];
$var1val = $endfile;
$var2val = "%%EOF";
echo $var2val;
echo $var1val;
$n = strcmp($var1val,$var2val); // 0 mean that they are the same
echo $n;
if ($n == 0) {
    echo "good";

} else {
    echo "corrupted";
}

?>
```

but I get this result :

```html
%%EOF %%EOF 1 corrupted
```

It gave me the same result with === .

I only tested with a working and not corrupted pdf. Do you know why this is not working ? Maybe you have other methods using php to check if the pdf is not corrupted before I automatically upload it to my server ?

Comment: So you are defining a PDF to be valid because it has an %%EOF marker?! That's somewhat strange as a single text file with this content would be treated as a valid PDF for you... You have to go more deeper into the file format to check for the validity of a PDF file.

Comment: I choosed this method depending on the pdf that i have generated. When I analyzed all my corrupted pdf, the EOF marker was never reached.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php :

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the newline still attached.** You need to remove the newlines to compare properly.

You need to do something like:

```
<?php
$file = file('good.pdf');
$endfile= trim($file[count($file) - 1]);
$n="%%EOF";


if ($endfile === $n) {
    echo "good";

} else {
    echo "corrupted";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it work just fine ;)

Answer (score 3):

I tested this out myself and noticed something:

```
php > echo $endfile;
%%EOF
php > echo strlen($endfile);
6
```

Looks like 5 characters, but it's actually 6.  There is a newline at the end:

```
php > var_dump($endfile == "%%EOF");
php shell code:1:
bool(false)
php > var_dump($endfile == "%%EOF\n");
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
```

So either compare with `$n="%%EOF\n";` or `trim($endfile);` first to remove the endline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is solved. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the start and the end of pdf content

```
<?php
$pdfFile=file('...file.pdf');
$end=trim(end($pdfFile));

if(substr($pdfFile[0],0,4)=='%PDF' && substr($end,-5)=='%%EOF')
{
   echo "IS GOOD";
}
```